# SQL view where clause with and or not working properly

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below view works perfectly. But the `AND` operator is not working properly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "public"."TESTe" AS 
SELECT 
    a.id,
    ar.role_id,
    ( SELECT (((a.duration * (a.frequency)::numeric) * (ar.percentage / (100)::numeric)) / (cw.workdays)::numeric) AS workdays
          FROM calculated_workday cw
          WHERE ((cw.organization = ( SELECT f.org_id FROM functions f WHERE (f.id = a.function))) 
          AND (((cw.year)::double precision = date_part('year'::text, now())) OR ((cw.year)::double precision = (date_part('year'::text, now()) - (1)::double precision))))) 
          AS total_duration
FROM activities a,
    activity_roles ar
WHERE (a.id = ar.activity_id);
```

Year part is expected to be the current year, which the `date_part()` is getting the current year as expected but the `AND OR` is not working and I get an error

> unexpected : more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Because there are entries for past years too, but i am expecting the AND to filter the year with the current year, if the data for the current year is not present then use the data from the past year.(OR operator)

Is the mistake with the brackets? I appreciate any help.

Comment: You could try to get rid of the scalar subquery.

Comment: Why are you still using `,` to join tables?  `JOIN` syntax was introduced in 1992, that's almost 30 years ago now.

Comment: "if the data for the current year is not present then use the data from the past year."  That is not what OR does.

Comment: actually subquery is workin good, first part og the Where clause is fine, but after AND condition is not workin.

Comment: so i am using OR wrong? what can i use instead?